# How get full info of runtime.getruntime.exec("netstat")

Tags: java, android, netstat

I can't get full info from netstat, from not rooted device.

If i use

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netstat -n");
```

with "-n" or other doesn't work.
how i read stream from netstat

```
process.getOutputStream().close();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
String line;
while ((line = reader.readline()) != null) {
// Parse line for required info
}
reader.close();
```

How can i get pid or process name with using netstat (or something other to monitor network activity) without root

I test it in android 6.0 and get only:

> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State
>   [click to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jw1rL.jpg)

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: I think the problem is in your "parse line" code.

Comment: i used text.append(line); in "parse line"

Answer (score 1):

You must get input stream from your process object and then read process output line by line until null line is received.

> Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address Foreign Address State

it's just the first line of netstat output.

For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13506836/4449456